# VSCode: Multiple horizontal and vertical panels

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to have mixed vertical and horizontal tabs/panels in VSCode - it seems I only can have either horizontal or vertical and no more than 3 total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now supported as of VS Code 1.25. The feature is called "Grid editor layout". You can read more about it [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_grid-editor-layout)

Grid layout lets you arrange editors vertically and horizontally. You can also put more than 3 editors next to each other